# Locate nexus 9 serial number

Tags: nexus-9

I have a defect nexus 9 tablet, which is getting stuck in the initialization animation (Marshmallow). I still have a warranty, but I can't locate the S/N. I stupidly didn't save the original box, and it isn't written on the back of the tablet.
btw, factory reset also didn't help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've finally found how to locate the s/n.
When the tablet is off, press "volume down" + power until the hboot menu appears. Then pick the barcode option, and there you can find the IMEI, S/N and MB codes.

Comment: What are the first 5 characters of your serial number. Mine is HT4CD (manufactured on December 13 2014) and runs Marshmallow perfectly better than Lollipop. Use https://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus9/comments/2nsqse/how_to_figure_out_when_htc_made_your_nexus_9/ to check the date (I can for you)